# Export first few pages of Doc to PDF using LibreOffice in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, command, libreoffice

I have been using LibreOffice in my rails app to convert my Doc to PDF using the command `/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir destination_path source_path/*.doc` in my rails app.

I planned to convert the entire Doc to PDF and display only a few pages of PDF, but it was not efficient to store the entire PDF only for preview purposes.

Is there a LibreOffice command or any other command that can help me export only the first few pages of Doc to PDF.

Comment: This isn't really a rails question, or even a programming question at all.  I would try this on SuperUser, since it's really about options for a linux command line app.

Comment: Having said that, however, a quick google reveals the following:  http://en.libreofficeforum.org/node/3151  Basically, convert the whole doc and then use the awesome `pdftk` to make a new pdf with just the pages you want, and then delete the full-sized pdf.

Comment: I am at present doing the same but with ghostscript. But this is adding more computational load to my server. I am looking for a better way.

Comment: Are you doing this conversion constantly then?  I assumed it would be a one-off big conversion (of all the existing doc files) and then just the occasional file here and there going forward.  Are your users constantly uploading word docs which you need to convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unoconv -f pdf -e PageRange=1-1 File.doc
```